# WP8 webview missing reference

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview

Im trying to add webview inside xaml. It gives this error. I ve searched but couldnt find the answer. Is it possible to add webview inside WP8 page.

```
   <Grid x:Name="todaysGrid" >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <WebView x:Name="webView1" Grid.Row="0"  Height="800"/>
   </Grid>

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'WebView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control is called [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks but now I have problem I give "www.google.com" as source but page can not be displayed what might be the reason ?